# iOS: How to get speed and speed limit in Here map?

Tags: ios, swift, here-maps-rest

I am using here map SDK in my iOS project and want to show user current speed and speed limit in navigation.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a "I need xyz code" forum. Please read [ask] and provide a [example] showing what you have already tried and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

speed limit from HERE:

https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.295516,-1.979556&waypoint1=52.295516,-1.979556&legattributes=li&mode=fastest;car&app_code=your_app_code&app_id=your_app_id

[A working example can be found on the](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#speed-limit-on-click__index)

Get Route Information

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/request-route-information.html